# How do I locate the realm file from VS 2019 or from the device on android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, realm

This is the path I see where the realm file is stored /data/user/0/com.companyname.app/files/default.realm but I can't find it and I have tried the adb pull method but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

For android simulator or rooted device, use:

```
adb pull /data/data/<packagename>/files/ .
```

For android not rooted device, try [this](https://gist.github.com/jk2K/a66ed67b252b880824b32dd4952d1b39). To run it on windows OS, we should install the `bash shell`.